# Twitter Bootstrap onclick not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

QUESTION BELOW

I'm currently making a responsive one-page website with Bootstrap 3.

There is a navbar at the top, and when there is a click on it, it should change how the navbar at the bottom looks like. Then when someone click's on the navbar at the bottom, it would change how the jumbotron in the middle looks like. I have tried many things, but nothing is working. Help would be much appreciated. My Current Code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pakistan Project</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <button id="demoUp" onclick="demo()">Demographics</button>
            <button id="geoUp" onclick="geo()">Geography</button>
            <button id="statsUp" onclick="stats()">Statistics</button>
    <script>
    function demo() {
       document.getElementById('lowerTitle').innerHTML = "Demographics";
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML = 'a';
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML = 'b';
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML = 'c';
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML = ;
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem5text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML}

      }
     function geo() {
       document.getElementById('lowerTitle').innerHTML = 'Geography'
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML = 
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML =
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem5text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML}
      }
        function stats() {
       document.getElementById('lowerTitle').innerHTML = 'Statistics';
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML = 'a';
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML = 'b';
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML = 'c';
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML = 'd';
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").innerHTML = 'f';
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML = 'f';
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML = 'd';
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML = 'd';
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML = 'e';
       document.getElementById("loweritem1text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem1text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem2text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem2text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem3text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem3text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem4text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem4text").innerHTML} 
       document.getElementById("loweritem5text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem6text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem6text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem7text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem7text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem8text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem8text").innerHTML}
       document.getElementById("loweritem9text").onclick = function() { document.getElementById('jumboInfo').innerHTML = ; 
       document.getElementById("jumboHeader").innerHTML = document.getElementById("loweritem9text").innerHTML}

      }
      </script>

          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a id="lowerTitle" class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="loweritem1"><a href="#" id="loweritem1text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem2"><a href="#" id="loweritem2text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem3"><a href="#" id="loweritem3text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem4"><a href="#" id="loweritem4text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem5"><a href="#" id="loweritem5text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem6"><a href="#" id="loweritem6text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem7"><a href="#" id="loweritem7text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem8"><a href="#" id="loweritem8text"></a></li>
      <li id="loweritem9"><a href="#" id="loweritem9text"></a></li>


          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 id="jumboHeader"></h1>
  <p id="jumboInfo"></p>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where there are blank equals signs, I am adding things to those later. But the onclick is the thing not working, not the equals sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, I suggest you use the jQuery shell for event handling. This way you won't disrupt what Bootstrap is already doing.

instead of using the onclick attribute here

```
<button id="demoUp" onclick="demo()">Demographics</button>
<button id="geoUp" onclick="geo()">Geography</button>
<button id="statsUp" onclick="stats()">Statistics</button>
```

add eventhandlers like this:

```
$('#demoUp').on('click', demo);
$('#geoUp').on('click', geo);
$('#statsUp').on('click', stats);
```

Comment: And how to use jquery? What libraries (If Any) Would I have to include in my HTML code? Thank you. (I'm quite the noob with this sort of thing)

Comment: You already have everything you need with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/ should be a good starting point.